# How do I calculate the number of turns or inductance while designing a transformer?

Tags: transformer, switch-mode-power-supply, dc-dc-converter, inductor, ac-dc

I was trying to design a transformer for a SMPS but can’t find any resource to calculate the number of turns and the core area. I know that the turns ratio has dependency with the signal frequency. If someone could refer a document explaining high frequency transformer design or explain here in brief, it would be great.

Comment: Consider Voltage ratio, Impedance , impedance ratio and energy storage to load ratios for flyback inductors.

Comment: I don’t have any specific voltage ratio requirement. Just interested to know as a generalised format.

Comment: Too many formulae , but these are the specs you ought to consider. The impedance of a transformer must be sufficiently higher than the load range, but have good mutual coupling.  Also the maximum current must not saturate the core with sufficent margin.

Comment: https://isatronick.be/12-steps-for-designing-smps-transformers/

Comment: And this https://www.coilcraft.com/en-us/tools/

Comment: Flyback or forward converter. The design of one is not the same at all as the design of the other. Choose a topology.

Answer (score 1):

TOPSWITCH application notes can be a great source of help. I think in AN-16 they explain how you determine the turn ratio.